# Set precision gives a zero after the decimal before the alloted digits

Tags: c++

When I try and round digits using setprecision(2) in C++, numbers like "0.093" re returned- THREE, not two digits after the decimal! I cannot figure out why this is.  I've included my very rudimentary code below, in case I am severely missing some point. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double tax = 0.06 ; //Tax Rate
    float cost ; //Cost of item
    float computed ; //Non-rounded tax

    cout << "Enter the cost of the item: " ;
    cin >> cost ;

    computed = tax*cost;

    cout << "Computed: $" << computed << endl;
    cout << "Charged: $" << setprecision(2) << computed << endl; //Computed tax rounded to 2 decimal places



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision, this asks for 2 digits _precision_ (2 significant digits), not 2 digits after the decimal point. Perhaps you should look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `std::setprecision` doesn't set the digits *after* the decimal point but the *significant* (aka "meaningful") digits if you don't change the floating point format to use a *fixed* number of digits after the decimal point. To change the format, you have to put [`std::fixed` (documentaion)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) into your output stream:

```
cout << "Charged: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << computed << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

The decimal precision determines the maximum number of digits to be written on insertion operations to express floating-point values. How this is interpreted depends on whether the floatfield format flag is set to a specific notation.
...

On the default floating-point notation, the precision field specifies the maximum number of meaningful digits to display in total counting both those before and those after the decimal point.

In your case: `0.093`, `93` - two meaningful digits.

Answer (score 0):

cout <<  fixed <<setprecision(6)<< a<<endl; // add whatever you want to round in the place of a